# ASP.NET losing connection to SQL Server Express after being published to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sql-server-express

I have an ASP.NET application that gets data from a SQL Server Express on the same computer. When I run the ASP.NET project from Visual Studio, the project can reach the database just fine. However, when published to IIS, the project loses the connection. Here is my connection string located in `Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conString" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Server = DESKTOP-EVAN\SERVER;Database=master;User ID=sa;Password=12345;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The project can be reached on the published IIS, however no data is there and no error messages show.

I've added the application pool and `NT Authority` to the SQL login but still no luck connection to the database.

Does anyone have any experience with this? How can I get my published ASP.NET project to connect to my SQL Server Express?

Comment: Is the IIS server on the same machine as the machine you run Visual Studio on?

Comment: Yes, the IIS server and Visual Studio are on the same machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried removing the spaces for the server like this:

```
 Server=DESKTOP-EVAN\SERVER
```

Comment: Yes, same problem

Comment: Your connection string is specifying the "master" database, are you sure that is correct? You typically would create a new database rather than using that one.

Comment: `master` is where the tables are, so that is correct. The connection works when running in visual studio, so I think the connection string is fine, but I'm not sure why it's not working when published

Comment: When you are running the site under VS the user is running as your local windows user. When you deploy to IIS it is running as the application pool user. Check what user this is running under by going to IIS > Sites > Right Click The Site > Manage WebSite > Advanced Settings. That is the user it is running as and that user may need to have SQL access. If you need to add a new application pool look here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/#how-to

Comment: Oh man... it was using the wrong application pool... It works now, thank you so much. I've been trying to solve this for way too long. I love you

Answer (score 3):

Did you **install** SQL Server Express on that machine where IIS is running, or on a machine that can be reached from the IIS machine?

**Also**: did you explicitly define a separate **instance name** for your SQL Server Express when installing?

By default, the instance name would be `SQLEXPRESS` - but you seem to refer to  `DESKTOP-EVAN\SERVER` - so `SERVER` would be your instance name - is that the case??

**If not**: can you try `DESKTOP-EVAN\SQLEXPRESS` as the server/instance name instead?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conString" 
         connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-EVAN\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;User ID=sa;Password=12345;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: The SQL Express Server and IIS are on the same machine. Yes, I just doubled checked, the instance name is `SERVER`. It works if I run from Visual Studio, the database updates the web pages, but when published to IIS the connection is lost.

Comment: @GreenSaber same problem. have you got a solution?

Comment: I have this working now, but it's been a while since I've posted this. Here is my new connection string in web.config, hope it helps: `<add name="conString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-EXAMPLE\DATABASE;Database=master;User ID=exampleuser;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />`

Answer (score 2):

You muss allow user for iis in security. Here is oné video:
https://youtu.be/rmVtxLKmkDU

I hope thats help you.

Comment: I have added IIS in security, but it's still not connecting